# Explode the "other_tags" Column of OSM Data Containing k-v Pairs in Postgis

Tags: postgis, postgresql, openstreetmap

I have a table of OSM data that includes "other_tags" column in the format like' *"maxspeed"=>"90","name:en"=>"Highway H-35","ref"=>"H-35","ref:en"=>"H-35","smoothness"=>"good","surface"=>"asphalt"* '. The length and k-v pairs are varied, for example sometimes it is just like '*"ref"=>"12"*'. How can I explode the column and create a column for each key? If a given row's pairs doesn't have a key, then the resulting column's value will contain NaN. I want to do this using a postgres query.

Comment: (https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/93656/geozelot?tab=profile) do you have any idea?

Comment: ...unfortunately, users that do not participate in posts are not notified when tagged. There currently is no simpler way than Erwin Brandstetters answer in @bugmenot's linked post within PostgreSQL.You can specify to dump tags into columns during OSM import in most import tools, if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, this is a `hstore` data type but in text form. You can turn it into a real `hstore` type by casting it.

```
SELECT CAST(other_tags AS hstore) ...
```

or

```
SELECT other_tags::hstore ...
```

Converting the data into actual columns is hard but here is a link to someone else's similar question and some answers on this network: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/94717/dynamically-convert-hstore-keys-into-columns-for-an-unknown-set-of-keys

Comment: it is like hstore but the type of column is "text" and I can't use the arrow operator to extract the value of a specific key.

Comment: You can cast the text to hstore, I added it to the post.

Comment: I tried that but I got: ERROR:  Unexpected end of string SQL state: XX000

Comment: Even for `SELECT '"maxspeed"=>"90","name:en"=>"Highway H-35","ref"=>"H-35","ref:en"=>"H-35","smoothness"=>"good","surface"=>"asphalt"'::hstore`?

Comment: 'SELECT '"maxspeed"=>"90","name:en"=>"Highway H-35","ref"=>"H-35","ref:en"=>"H-35","smoothness"=>"good","surface"=>"asphalt"'::hstore' works but 'SELECT other_tags::hstore ...' does not.

Comment: Sorry, then I do not know what is wrong :(